# Building hand model and its projections in Maya

Tags: model, projection, maya

As part of a hand detection problem I would like to build 3D hand model and export its projections (e.g. rotation 15..+15 degrees on X, -5..+5 on Z axis..., scale...) to images for template matching.

Is Maya suitable for this (I don't know how to build and export model projections (> 300) - NOT MANUAL) ?

Comment: I think this question is probably best suited for a Maya forum. Is it specifically related to the programming API or is this a general "How do I do this in Maya" question?

Comment: I'm searching for an modeling application, or set of applications (e.g. Maya -> export in specific format -> load in some other app -> export projection images) (I have no expirience in modeling) which can provide me an easiest way to do this (modeling + prjection images export).

Comment: So this isn't a programming question, I assume. Yea unfortunately StackOverflow is not the right place for this question. It should be programming related. If you were asking for a way to do something specifically with the Maya API (in code) then it might be relevant here.

Comment: Ok, then I'm asking how to make a script (or something else) that will export model projection images from 3D model built in Maya (I want to skip doing that manually).

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the manual process for doing a single operation, and you want to create a script to reproduce the approach in an automated fashion, the easiest thing to do is to watch the script editor as you perform a single process and document all of the commands that are performed. From this, you can piece together a script.

Maya provides both a [high level python commands module](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2012/en_us/CommandsPython/index.html), and also a [lower level python binding to the C++ API](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/index.html).

If you are just getting started learning Maya scripting, I can do a shameless plug and recommend my 2 learning tutorials for Python Programming in Maya: [Vol1](http://www.cmivfx.com/tutorials/view/320/Python+Introduction+Vol+01+-+Maya) & [Vol2](http://www.cmivfx.com/tutorials/view/328/Python+For+Maya+Vol+02)